# How to embed Python 2.4 in C++ application using VS C++ 6.0?

Tags: c++, python, visual-c++, visual-studio-6

I get this linking error, using Python 2.4 and MS VC++ 6:

```
Linking...
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Finalize
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Occurred
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Print
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_AsLong
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_CallObject
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyTuple_SetItem
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_FromLong
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _atoi
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyTuple_New
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyCallable_Check
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyImport_Import
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromString
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Initialize
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fprintf
testPyEmb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob
```

Adding this to my source file did not help:

```
#undef _DEBUG
```

I modified pyconfig.h to disable debug mode and force use of python24.lib instead of python24_d.lib as shown here: http://tutorial.debashis.net/?p=57&cpage=1
Still, same error.

What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added *python24.lib* and its path to the linker options?

Comment: Yeap, I added python24.lib and its path to the linker options.

Answer (score 9):

Since you say that you are linking against the .lib, it may be that you have installed the 64 bit version of Python, and are thus linking against 64-bit version of the .lib file, but your build configuration is (I suspect) 32 bit. Go to Configuration Manager and change it to 64 bit.

Hope this helps.
Marius.

Comment: I changed my configuration to x64 and then the project could no longer link with MSVCP120.dll.